# Python pymodbus rtu cant write registers

Tags: python, linux, modbus, pymodbus

I have a problem writing a holding register using the pymodbus library. I am not quite sure what the problem is.

I am sending a modbus frame and getting a correct response back from the slave, but still the register is not being written.

example code:

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient
import time
import logging

FORMAT = (
    "%(asctime)-15s %(threadName)-15s "
    "%(levelname)-8s %(module)-15s:%(lineno)-8s %(message)s"
)
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

client = ModbusSerialClient(method = "rtu", port="/dev/ttyAMA0",stopbits=2, bytesize=8, parity='N', baudrate=9600, timeout=1, rtscts=0, dsrdtr=0, xonxoff=0, exclusive=0)

client.connect()
log.debug("Write to a holding register and read back")
client.read_holding_registers(101, 6, unit=17)
client.write_registers(101, [56711,18462,0,56577,56666,22558] , unit=17)
client.read_holding_registers(101, 6, unit=17)
client.close()
```

result:

```
2022-06-14 21:00:04,199 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :110      Current transaction state - IDLE
2022-06-14 21:00:04,199 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :115      Running transaction 1
2022-06-14 21:00:04,200 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :206      SEND: 0x11 0x3 0x0 0x65 0x0 0x6 0xd7 0x47
2022-06-14 21:00:04,200 MainThread      DEBUG    sync           :75       New Transaction state 'SENDING'
2022-06-14 21:00:04,210 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :209      Changing transaction state from 'SENDING' to 'WAITING FOR REPLY'
2022-06-14 21:00:04,237 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :284      Changing transaction state from 'WAITING FOR REPLY' to 'PROCESSING REPLY'
2022-06-14 21:00:04,238 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :214      RECV: 0x11 0x3 0xc 0xdd 0x87 0x48 0x1e 0x0 0x0 0xdd 0x1 0xdd 0x5a 0x56 0x1e 0x97 0xa3
2022-06-14 21:00:04,238 MainThread      DEBUG    rtu_framer     :175      Getting Frame - 0x3 0xc 0xdd 0x87 0x48 0x1e 0x0 0x0 0xdd 0x1 0xdd 0x5a 0x56 0x1e
2022-06-14 21:00:04,238 MainThread      DEBUG    factory        :246      Factory Response[ReadHoldingRegistersResponse: 3]
2022-06-14 21:00:04,239 MainThread      DEBUG    rtu_framer     :110      Frame advanced, resetting header!!
2022-06-14 21:00:04,239 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :418      Adding transaction 1
2022-06-14 21:00:04,239 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :180      Changing transaction state from 'PROCESSING REPLY' to 'TRANSACTION_COMPLETE'
2022-06-14 21:00:04,239 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :110      Current transaction state - TRANSACTION_COMPLETE
2022-06-14 21:00:04,239 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :115      Running transaction 2
2022-06-14 21:00:04,240 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :206      SEND: 0x11 0x10 0x0 0x65 0x0 0x6 0xc 0xdd 0x87 0x48 0x1e 0x0 0x0 0xdd 0x1 0xdd 0x5a 0x58 0x1e 0x35 0xd0
2022-06-14 21:00:04,240 MainThread      DEBUG    rtu_framer     :252      Changing state to IDLE - Last Frame End - 1655233204.237538, Current Time stamp - 1655233204.240361
2022-06-14 21:00:04,240 MainThread      DEBUG    rtu_framer     :260      Waiting for 3.5 char before next send - 4.01 ms
2022-06-14 21:00:04,244 MainThread      DEBUG    sync           :75       New Transaction state 'SENDING'
2022-06-14 21:00:04,245 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :209      Changing transaction state from 'SENDING' to 'WAITING FOR REPLY'
2022-06-14 21:00:04,283 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :284      Changing transaction state from 'WAITING FOR REPLY' to 'PROCESSING REPLY'
2022-06-14 21:00:04,284 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :214      RECV: 0x11 0x10 0x0 0x65 0x0 0x6 0x52 0x84
2022-06-14 21:00:04,284 MainThread      DEBUG    rtu_framer     :175      Getting Frame - 0x10 0x0 0x65 0x0 0x6
2022-06-14 21:00:04,284 MainThread      DEBUG    factory        :246      Factory Response[WriteMultipleRegistersResponse: 16]
2022-06-14 21:00:04,284 MainThread      DEBUG    rtu_framer     :110      Frame advanced, resetting header!!
2022-06-14 21:00:04,285 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :418      Adding transaction 2
2022-06-14 21:00:04,285 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :180      Changing transaction state from 'PROCESSING REPLY' to 'TRANSACTION_COMPLETE'
2022-06-14 21:00:04,285 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :110      Current transaction state - TRANSACTION_COMPLETE
2022-06-14 21:00:04,285 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :115      Running transaction 3
2022-06-14 21:00:04,286 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :206      SEND: 0x11 0x10 0x0 0x65 0x0 0x6 0xc 0xdd 0x87 0x48 0x1e 0x0 0x0 0xdd 0x1 0xdd 0x5a 0x58 0x1e 0x35 0xd0
2022-06-14 21:00:04,286 MainThread      DEBUG    rtu_framer     :252      Changing state to IDLE - Last Frame End - 1655233204.283695, Current Time stamp - 1655233204.286256
2022-06-14 21:00:04,286 MainThread      DEBUG    rtu_framer     :260      Waiting for 3.5 char before next send - 4.01 ms
2022-06-14 21:00:04,290 MainThread      DEBUG    sync           :75       New Transaction state 'SENDING'
2022-06-14 21:00:04,291 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :209      Changing transaction state from 'SENDING' to 'WAITING FOR REPLY'
2022-06-14 21:00:04,329 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :284      Changing transaction state from 'WAITING FOR REPLY' to 'PROCESSING REPLY'
2022-06-14 21:00:04,329 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :214      RECV: 0x11 0x10 0x0 0x65 0x0 0x6 0x52 0x84
2022-06-14 21:00:04,330 MainThread      DEBUG    rtu_framer     :175      Getting Frame - 0x10 0x0 0x65 0x0 0x6
2022-06-14 21:00:04,330 MainThread      DEBUG    factory        :246      Factory Response[WriteMultipleRegistersResponse: 16]
2022-06-14 21:00:04,330 MainThread      DEBUG    rtu_framer     :110      Frame advanced, resetting header!!
2022-06-14 21:00:04,330 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :418      Adding transaction 3
2022-06-14 21:00:04,330 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :180      Changing transaction state from 'PROCESSING REPLY' to 'TRANSACTION_COMPLETE'
2022-06-14 21:00:04,331 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :110      Current transaction state - TRANSACTION_COMPLETE
2022-06-14 21:00:04,331 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :115      Running transaction 4
2022-06-14 21:00:04,331 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :206      SEND: 0x11 0x10 0x0 0x65 0x0 0x6 0xc 0xdd 0x87 0x48 0x1e 0x0 0x0 0xdd 0x1 0xdd 0x5a 0x58 0x1e 0x35 0xd0
2022-06-14 21:00:04,331 MainThread      DEBUG    rtu_framer     :252      Changing state to IDLE - Last Frame End - 1655233204.329432, Current Time stamp - 1655233204.331866
2022-06-14 21:00:04,332 MainThread      DEBUG    rtu_framer     :260      Waiting for 3.5 char before next send - 4.01 ms
2022-06-14 21:00:04,336 MainThread      DEBUG    sync           :75       New Transaction state 'SENDING'
2022-06-14 21:00:04,336 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :209      Changing transaction state from 'SENDING' to 'WAITING FOR REPLY'
2022-06-14 21:00:04,375 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :284      Changing transaction state from 'WAITING FOR REPLY' to 'PROCESSING REPLY'
2022-06-14 21:00:04,375 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :214      RECV: 0x11 0x10 0x0 0x65 0x0 0x6 0x52 0x84
2022-06-14 21:00:04,375 MainThread      DEBUG    rtu_framer     :175      Getting Frame - 0x10 0x0 0x65 0x0 0x6
2022-06-14 21:00:04,376 MainThread      DEBUG    factory        :246      Factory Response[WriteMultipleRegistersResponse: 16]
2022-06-14 21:00:04,376 MainThread      DEBUG    rtu_framer     :110      Frame advanced, resetting header!!
2022-06-14 21:00:04,376 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :418      Adding transaction 4
2022-06-14 21:00:04,376 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :180      Changing transaction state from 'PROCESSING REPLY' to 'TRANSACTION_COMPLETE'
2022-06-14 21:00:04,376 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :110      Current transaction state - TRANSACTION_COMPLETE
2022-06-14 21:00:04,377 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :115      Running transaction 5
2022-06-14 21:00:04,377 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :206      SEND: 0x11 0x10 0x0 0x65 0x0 0x6 0xc 0xdd 0x87 0x48 0x1e 0x0 0x0 0xdd 0x1 0xdd 0x5a 0x58 0x1e 0x35 0xd0
2022-06-14 21:00:04,377 MainThread      DEBUG    rtu_framer     :252      Changing state to IDLE - Last Frame End - 1655233204.375116, Current Time stamp - 1655233204.377633
2022-06-14 21:00:04,377 MainThread      DEBUG    rtu_framer     :260      Waiting for 3.5 char before next send - 4.01 ms
2022-06-14 21:00:04,382 MainThread      DEBUG    sync           :75       New Transaction state 'SENDING'
2022-06-14 21:00:04,382 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :209      Changing transaction state from 'SENDING' to 'WAITING FOR REPLY'
2022-06-14 21:00:04,421 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :284      Changing transaction state from 'WAITING FOR REPLY' to 'PROCESSING REPLY'
2022-06-14 21:00:04,421 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :214      RECV: 0x11 0x10 0x0 0x65 0x0 0x6 0x52 0x84
2022-06-14 21:00:04,421 MainThread      DEBUG    rtu_framer     :175      Getting Frame - 0x10 0x0 0x65 0x0 0x6
2022-06-14 21:00:04,422 MainThread      DEBUG    factory        :246      Factory Response[WriteMultipleRegistersResponse: 16]
2022-06-14 21:00:04,422 MainThread      DEBUG    rtu_framer     :110      Frame advanced, resetting header!!
2022-06-14 21:00:04,422 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :418      Adding transaction 5
2022-06-14 21:00:04,422 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :180      Changing transaction state from 'PROCESSING REPLY' to 'TRANSACTION_COMPLETE'
2022-06-14 21:00:04,423 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :110      Current transaction state - TRANSACTION_COMPLETE
2022-06-14 21:00:04,423 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :115      Running transaction 6
2022-06-14 21:00:04,423 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :206      SEND: 0x11 0x3 0x0 0x65 0x0 0x6 0xd7 0x47
2022-06-14 21:00:04,423 MainThread      DEBUG    rtu_framer     :252      Changing state to IDLE - Last Frame End - 1655233204.42094, Current Time stamp - 1655233204.423644
2022-06-14 21:00:04,423 MainThread      DEBUG    rtu_framer     :260      Waiting for 3.5 char before next send - 4.01 ms
2022-06-14 21:00:04,428 MainThread      DEBUG    sync           :75       New Transaction state 'SENDING'
2022-06-14 21:00:04,438 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :209      Changing transaction state from 'SENDING' to 'WAITING FOR REPLY'
2022-06-14 21:00:04,465 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :284      Changing transaction state from 'WAITING FOR REPLY' to 'PROCESSING REPLY'
2022-06-14 21:00:04,465 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :214      RECV: 0x11 0x3 0xc 0xdd 0x87 0x48 0x1e 0x0 0x0 0xdd 0x1 0xdd 0x5a 0x56 0x1e 0x97 0xa3
2022-06-14 21:00:04,466 MainThread      DEBUG    rtu_framer     :175      Getting Frame - 0x3 0xc 0xdd 0x87 0x48 0x1e 0x0 0x0 0xdd 0x1 0xdd 0x5a 0x56 0x1e
2022-06-14 21:00:04,466 MainThread      DEBUG    factory        :246      Factory Response[ReadHoldingRegistersResponse: 3]
2022-06-14 21:00:04,466 MainThread      DEBUG    rtu_framer     :110      Frame advanced, resetting header!!
2022-06-14 21:00:04,466 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :418      Adding transaction 6
2022-06-14 21:00:04,467 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :180      Changing transaction state from 'PROCESSING REPLY' to 'TRANSACTION_COMPLETE'
```

as you can see before I try to write registers readings are:

0x11 0x3 0xc 0xdd 0x87 0x48 0x1e 0x0 0x0 0xdd 0x1 0xdd 0x5a **0x56** 0x1e 0x97 0xa3

and then I try to write register with:

0x11 0x10 0x0 0x65 0x0 0x6 0xc 0xdd 0x87 0x48 0x1e 0x0 0x0 0xdd 0x1 0xdd 0x5a **0x58** 0x1e 0x35 0xd0

and I get response:

0x11 0x10 0x0 0x65 0x0 0x6 0x52 0x84

as I understand it means everything went OK, but when I try to read registers again, result are:

0x11 0x3 0xc 0xdd 0x87 0x48 0x1e 0x0 0x0 0xdd 0x1 0xdd 0x5a **0x56** 0x1e 0x97 0xa3

same as before...

am I do something wrong?

Comment: Your code and the packets sent/received look fine and I would expect the register to have been updated (but the second read indicates it was not). It's possible that the issue is with the slave? (some devices do not follow expected norms). Perhaps try writing a single register (`write_register`).

Comment: I tried before with single register writing. Slave did not even give an response. I also tried another python library (minimalmodbus), but the result is the same. Is it possible that the serial port settings are wrong? I seem to be getting the right response, but who knows?

Comment: Something is responding to your Modbus requests so the comm port settings are ok (the messages use CRC to validate correct transmission). Please provide info on the device (few devices support all Modbus commands).